# Detect duplicate code within ASP.NET MVC project in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2013, code-duplication

Is there any way at all to detect duplicate code within ASP.NET MVC project in Visual Studio 2013 Professional???

I want to detect duplicate JavaScript functions within the cshtml files in the Views.

I've been searching forever and can't find a viable solution.

Answer (score -1):

Our [JavaScript CloneDR](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Clone/) code duplication detector should be able to do this.  (This obviously isn't part of VS 2013.)

Its parser can read plain Javascript, and/or html-like pages that contain JavaScript chunks in Script tags, and/or HTML script attributes (e.g., *OnXXX=* ).  You can hand it lots of files and it will find clones across the files.

You can see examples of what it detects at the link.